# How to move git commits common to multiple branches earlier in the main branch history?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick, git-history-rewrite

I have a git repo that looks like this:

```
   /C''-D''-F (featureB)
A-B-C---D---E (main)
   \C'--D'--G (featureA)
```

I would like to move the common commits `C` and `D` earlier in the `main` branch
history so that the repo looks like this:

```
       /F (featureB)
A-B-C-D-E (main)
       \G (featureA)
```

It is important to note that the `C`/`C'`/`C''` and `D`/`D'`/`D''` commits modify the code identically, but due to being in different branches, they all have different commit hashes.

Comment: Are C and D actually the same exact commit, with the same commit hashes, in all three branches? If so, it's not clear that there's a difference between your two situations. A branch is really just a list of commits, and `featureB` for example has the same list in both examples. So you might want to clarify your question. Also: try to make your question as specific as possible; nobody here wants to sit down and write a general `git rebase` tutorial for you when there's plenty of good [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) that you could read.

Comment: @Caleb: They modify the code identically but have different commit hashes across the three branches.

Comment: @Caleb: Thanks I will clarify the question to mention that `C` and `D` have different commit hashes.

Comment: It's better to give them different names to make that clear, usually we use `C'` to designate a commit that is basically the same as C, but not quite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's rephrase the task at hand:

> I want to take the changes of the N latest commits of a branch and move/copy them in a way that their parent commit becomes a different one.

This is what [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) allows you to do. You can tell it which range of commits to copy and onto which parent commit you want to copy it:

```
git rebase --onto main^ featureA^ featureA
git rebase --onto main^ featureB^ featureB
```

will rebase the latest commit of featureA and featureB onto the second last commit of branch main. You can also use the commit hashes directly:

```
git rebase --onto D D' featureA
git rebase --onto D D'' featureB
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @knittl. It seems however that `git rebase main featureA` results in `error: could not apply 697g054... G`. I think git rebase is trying to merge the commit `G` at the end of `featureA`, even though I still would like `G` to be on a separate branch as shown in the second diagram. Is there a way we can modify your commands to enable this?

Comment: I think @procyon wants to rebase `--onto main~1` or `main^` (commit `D`-on-`main`), not onto `main` itself (commit `E`).

Comment: @torek you are right, I selected the wrong target. Let me quickly fix that :)

Comment: knittl, your latest answer works great! Thanks to you and @torek for rephrasing my question to show what I actually meant :)

Answer (score 1):

> [C and D]...modify the code identically but have different commit hashes across the three branches.

In that case you'll probably want to first remove the C and D commits from your two feature branches, and then rebase to the main branch. You can use `git rebase -i` to do the first part, using the `drop` option for the the commits you don't want. Then (from each branch) `git rebase main` to replay the commits in each branch on top of the current state of the `main` branch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Caleb. It seems however that `git rebase main` after dropping `C` and `D` from `featureA` using `git rebase -i` results in `error: could not apply 697g054... G`. I think git rebase is trying to merge the commit `G` at the end of `featureA`, even though I still would like `G` to be on a separate branch as shown in the second diagram. Is there a way we can modify your commands to enable this?

Comment: That sounds like you've got a merge conflict; is it possible that `C` and `C'` or `D` and `D'` aren't actually *exactly* identical, even if they're effectively the same? Even differences in white space could be a problem. In any case, if there's a conflict, you should also see a message about that and an instruction to run `git rebase --continue` once you've fixed the problem. Run `git status` to figure out which file(s) are affected, and then look for merge markers (e.g. `<<<<<`, `>>>>>`) in them. There are definitely existing SO questions about resolving merge conflicts, so check those out.